# What language coined the term lvalue?

Tags: c++, c, terminology, history, lvalue

Was C the first programming language to use the term *lvalue*, or does it go further back? Note that I'm not talking about the general concept of "something on the left-hand side of an assignment statement" (which it has ceased to mean in C++ a long time ago). You can find that in pretty much any imperative programming language. I am specifically asking about the term *lvalue*. Where does it come from?

Comment: Nice question, but is actually off topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The notion of lvalues and rvalues was introduced by [CPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPL_%28programming_language%29).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-value

This link doesn't go directly for some reason...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Programming_Language

Answer (score 2):

The terms are coined in computer science, the notion of lvalues and rvalues were [introduced by CPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29)  More can be found in that article.